# Pythonのスクレイピングをクラウド上で（できれば並列化して）行いたい

Tags: python, web-scraping

Pythonでairbnbのサイトをスクレイピングしようとしています。
PCを閉じていても定期的に動くようにしたいので、スクレイピングの処理をクラウド上で、できれば並列化して行いたいと考えております。（スクレイピング自体のコードはできています）
おすすめの方法などありましたら教えて頂けると有難いです。

Answer (score 2):

クラウド環境という制約の元、簡単にまとめてみました。

## 仮想サーバ（VPS、EC2、GCEなど）内で定期実行する方法

- cronを利用し、定期的にスクリプトを起動する

  - cronとはジョブを定期的に実行するデーモンで、分単位で実行タイミングを指定することができます。
  - [cron - ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.jp/index.php/Cron)
- アプリケーションを常時起動しつつ、定期的に取得処理を動かす

  - Pythonだとscheduleというライブラリが便利です。しかし、この方式の場合アプリケーションが予定外の終了をした場合の対応が必要です。
  - [schedule — schedule 0.4.0 documentation](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

これらの方式は伝統的であり、ドキュメントも多いですが、サーバを常時起動するコストや、サーバ自体の監視・メンテナンスコストが発生します。

そこで、近年は以下の方式がより主流になりつつあります。

## FaaS系サービスを利用し、関数を定期実行してもらう方法

- AWS LambdaやGoogle Cloud Functionsで関数を登録し、cronのように定期実行することができます。この場合、並列化したい関数（以下関数A）と、並列化したい関数を呼び出す関数（以下関数B）を登録しておいて、関数Bを定期実行し、そこから別途関数Aを呼び出すような形式になるかと存じます。

  - [AWS Lambda (サーバーレスでコードを実行・自動管理) | AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/jp/lambda/)
  - [Cloud Functions - イベント駆動型のサーバーレス コンピューティング  |  Cloud Functions  |  Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/functions/?hl=ja)

ただし、こちらの方式はローカルにデータを保存出来ないため、データ保存先を別途用意する必要があります。また、FaaSの流儀に従ったコードを書く必要もあります（関数名や、実行時間に制限がある）。

どちらを選ぶかは要件に合わせて選択してください。

Comment: ありがとうございます！正直、具体的な手順まで理解できていませんが、教えていただいた情報を基に色々試してみようと思います。