# Python スクレイピング環境

Tags: python, web-scraping

PythonでスクレイピングするならJupyter Notebookよりもコマンドプロンプトで書いた方がいいのですか？理由も含めてお願いします。
※スクレイピングに関する本を何冊か読んだところJupyter notebookでスクレイピングしているものが見当たらなかったため質問させていただきました！

Comment: あなた自身はなぜそのように思ったのかも質問に含めておくと、回答が付きやすいと思います。

Comment: スクレイピングの目的は何でしょう？WEBページンリンクを辿って、データを収集するならスクリプトを実行して、長時間稼働させると思われるので、コマンドプロンプトというよりVScodeなどのデバッグできるIDE環境が良いと思います。またデータ収集再開（エラー等が出て停止してもその続きができる）可能なように記述するのが良いかと思います。

Answer (score 1):

どんなことでもそうですが、単純なあるいは絶対的な優劣というものはそうそう無いでしょう。
あるソフトウェアを統合開発環境(IDE)やデバッガから動作させるか、単独で動作させるか程度の違いと思われます。
ちょっとした性能差や動作環境の違いを考慮する必要があるかもしれませんが、それらが特に気にならない場合はどちらの方法でもたいして変わりはありません。

---

書籍として書かれたものには少ないのかもしれませんが、Web上で検索すれば以下のように割と直ぐに見つかります。
[python + JupyterLab で Web スクレイピング](https://qiita.com/takiguchi-yu/items/1911252d97321c1f9d9b)
[Pythonでスクレイピングして遊んでみる](https://inglow.jp/techblog/python-scraping/)
[【Win10】Python で スクレイピング【Jupyter Notebook 第4回】](https://tks-kan.com/2019/06/14/5318/)
[プログラミング Pythonを始める！ 第3回Webスクレイピングやってみる＜Windows用＞](https://rakumoke.hatenablog.com/entry/2020/09/13/130000)
[データ収集を大幅に効率化する「スクレイピング」とは？ 手法やルール・注意点を解説！](https://data.wingarc.com/scraping-27053)
[面倒な「ブラウザ操作」や「データ収集」の作業はPythonで自動化しよう｜スクレイピングとは何か？できることや使い方をわかりやすく解説【PythonでやるRPA】](https://kino-code.com/python_automation_web_scraping/)
[Pythonのスクレイピングを勉強しています。](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q12237487512)

---

なのであなたの調べた範囲に見当たらず、質問のように思えたのは「たまたま」そうだった、と考えられます。

実際には、使っていくうちに何か問題に遭遇したり、評価の優先順位が変わったりして他に切り替えた方が良いという可能性も考えられますが、それはその時に考えても遅くは無いでしょう。
例えばこんな要求が出てくることもあります。
[Pythonのスクレイピングをクラウド上で（できれば並列化して）行いたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/54243/26370)

今あなたのやりたいこと、既に分かっている各環境の機能・性能の有無・優劣、あなたが何を重視するか等を詳細化(必要ならば調査を継続)して、それらを元に判断すれば良いと思われます。